# How to add name attribute to <td> tag while adding rows dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using Jquery to add rows dynamically. The problem is I am not able to assign `"name"` attribute to the table cell. I know how to add `"name"` attribute when we are creating `input type="text"` element in the cells, but here I do not want to see the values in the text boxes.

My problem is I am not able to assign `"name"` attribute to my table cells so that I can access their values by

```
document.getElementByNames("anyName")[0].value
```

My code:

```
function addRow() {
var carName = "fiat";
var Engine = "Petrol";
$("#datble").append("<tr><td>"+carName+"</td><td>"+Engine+"</td></tr>")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `name` for `td`, it is not a valid attribute for `td`, use `class` instead

```
var i=0;
function addRow() {
  var carName = "fiat";
  var Engine = "Petrol";
  $("#datble").append("<tr><td class='anyClass"+i+"0'>"+carName+"</td><td class='anyClass"+i+"1'>"+Engine+"</td></tr>");
  i++;
}
```

Now access the values using `class selector` like `$(".anyClass00").html();`

**EDIT:**
Used `i` to make it more dynamic in nature!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I need name attribute , because I am using Spring MVC and in that I can access value by name attribute only. So now my question is: can i give name attribute same as you are giving class?

Comment: Yes just replace `class` with `name` and then use `$("[name='anyName00']")` to select the element.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But with your reply I can access by .html() . Is there any chance i can get value by using .value . Because this is my basic need as mentioned in question. I want to access using document.getElementsByName("anyName")[0].value

Comment: No for that you need to make it a readonly input inside the td and instead of assigning the class to td assign it to input inside td.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot.. Anyway thanks for clarification !!

Comment: I don't have enough reputation for upvoting.. But I do not want to accept it as answer, it may misguide others will visit in future.